# How to unchecked all checked checkbox in angular 6

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, checkbox

I have a dynamic list of data, and each element is shown as a checkbox. 
The elements I checked are saved in an array. After I save the array, I want all the checked checkbox to be unchecked when I press a button, but it doesn't work.

I want to unchecked the selected checkbox after I saved the array. Please help me to find a solution. Thanks.

[Stackblitz link here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-checkbox-unchekall?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

#### ts file:

```
export class AppComponent  {
 userRoleListTemp: any = [];
 userRoleListToSave: any = [];
 checkedInfo: any;

 appUserRoleList: any = [
    {id: '1', roleName: 'SETUP_ROLE'},
    {id: '2', roleName: 'ENTRY_ROLE'},
    {id: '3', roleName: 'SEATPLAN_ROLE'},
    {id: '4', roleName: 'MARKSENTRY_ROLE'},
    {id: '5', roleName: 'APPLICANT_ROLE'}
 ];

 constructor() {}

 onChangeRole(userRole: string, isChecked) {
    this.checkedInfo = isChecked;
    if (isChecked.target.checked) {
        this.userRoleListTemp.push(userRole);
    } else {
        let index = this.userRoleListTemp.indexOf(userRole);
        this.userRoleListTemp.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  checkedEvnt() {
    this.checkedInfo.target.checked = false;
  }

}
```

#### html file:

```
<h1>Unchek All Roles</h1>

 <div class="form-check" *ngFor="let appUserRole of appUserRoleList">

 <input class="form-check-input" name="{{appUserRole.roleName}}" 
   type="checkbox" id="{{appUserRole.roleName}}" 
   (change)="onChangeRole(appUserRole.roleName, $event)">

 <label class="form-check-label" for="{{appUserRole.roleName}}">
  {{appUserRole.roleName}}
 </label> 

</div>
<button (change)="checkedEvnt()">Uncheck All</button>

<pre>{{ userRoleListTemp | json}}</pre>
```

Comment: If you use angular reactive forms, loop over all the checkbox controls and unset the value.

Comment: There are two approaches for this. Either modify your data and add a property that you'll bind to the `checked` property.
Or use template variable for your checkboxes and access them in your .ts file. I believe both options have been mentioned in the answers. Just choose the one you're comfortable with!

Comment: @monir, Why not use [(ngModel)] it's more easy, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First mistake you made is you are adding `(change)` event on button click. Replace it with `(click)` as change event if for input type properties and you can only use it with [**ngModel**](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel).

You should add `isChecked` property inside `appUserRoleList` list, which will help you to check/uncheck checkbox. 
Try this:

```
  appUserRoleList: any = [
        {id: '1', roleName: 'SETUP_ROLE', isChecked: true},
        {id: '2', roleName: 'ENTRY_ROLE', isChecked: false},
        {id: '3', roleName: 'SEATPLAN_ROLE', isChecked: true},
        {id: '4', roleName: 'MARKSENTRY_ROLE', isChecked: true},
        {id: '5', roleName: 'APPLICANT_ROLE', isChecked: true}
    ];
```

On `Uncheck All` button click loop though the `appUserRoleList` and set `isChecked = false`.

Here is the working [**example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-checkbox-unchekall-zmrqc2?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Answer (score 3):

Use a template variable to get a hold of the checkboxes:

```
<input #checkboxes class="form-check-input" name="{{appUserRole.roleName}}" type="checkbox" id="{{appUserRole.roleName}}" (change)="onChangeRole(appUserRole.roleName, $event)">
```

Then in your component using `@ViewChild` get a hold of all the `ElementRef` and process them by setting the `checked` property to `false`:

```
@ViewChildren("checkboxes") checkboxes: QueryList<ElementRef>
checkedEvnt() {
         this.checkboxes.forEach((element) => {
              element.nativeElement.checked = false;
              this.userRoleListTemp.length = 0;
    });
}
```

This is your modified [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-checkbox-unchekall-hxz5nf)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-me1cdb?file=src/app/app.component.html

I am using `isChecked` flag it will help you

```js
 appUserRoleList: any = [
        {id: '1', roleName: 'SETUP_ROLE',isChecked:false},
        {id: '2', roleName: 'ENTRY_ROLE',isChecked:false},
        {id: '3', roleName: 'SEATPLAN_ROLE',isChecked:false},
        {id: '4', roleName: 'MARKSENTRY_ROLE',isChecked:true},
        {id: '5', roleName: 'APPLICANT_ROLE',isChecked:false} 
    ];


    onChangeRole(userRole: string, isChecked) {
        this.checkedInfo = isChecked;
         for(var i=0;i<this.appUserRoleList.length;i++ ){
           if( this.appUserRoleList[i].roleName==userRole){

          this.appUserRoleList[i].isChecked=!this.appUserRoleList[i].isChecked;
           }
        }
    }

    checkedEvnt() {
        for(var i=0;i<this.appUserRoleList.length;i++ ){
          this.appUserRoleList[i].isChecked=false;
                    console.log(this.appUserRoleList[i].isChecked)

        }
    }
```

```html
<h1>Unchek All Roles</h1>

<div class="form-check" *ngFor="let appUserRole of appUserRoleList">

  <input class="form-check-input" name="{{appUserRole.roleName}}" type="checkbox" id="{{appUserRole.roleName}}" [checked]="appUserRole.isChecked" (change)="onChangeRole(appUserRole.roleName, $event)">

  <label class="form-check-label" for="{{appUserRole.roleName}}">
      {{appUserRole.roleName}}
  </label> 

</div>

<button (click)="checkedEvnt()">Uncheck All</button>

<pre>{{ userRoleListTemp | json}}</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

why not use [(ngModel)]?? NO (change), NO split. Maintain the code simple. See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-checkbox-unchekall-xbcafp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<div class="form-check" *ngFor="let appUserRole of appUserRoleList">

  <input #inputs class="form-check-input" name="{{appUserRole.roleName}}" type="checkbox" id="{{appUserRole.roleName}}" [(ngModel)]="appUserRole.checked">

  <label class="form-check-label" for="{{appUserRole.roleName}}">
      {{appUserRole.roleName}}
  </label> 

</div>
```

To get the array, I like a getter

```
  get userRoleListTemp()
  {
    return this.appUserRoleList.filter(x=>x.checked).map(u=>+u.id)
  }
```