# How to get multiple checkbox values in a single <td>

Tags: angular, checkbox, html-table

I have a table with checkbox in a single `td`. I have to find value for every checkbox in the table. How can I achieve?

```
 <tr id="trval" *ngFor="let x of csvData">
   <td id="td" (click)="click($event)" contenteditable *ngFor="let y of x;let j=index" [class.active]="i == selectedRow">
     <i *ngIf="j==0" id="removeicon" class="fa fa-times-circle icon " aria-hidden="true" readonly="true" (click)="deleterow($event)"></i>
     <div *ngIf="j==23" contenteditable>
       <input type="checkbox" id="dppcheck" (change)="dppflagchecked()">
     </div>
     <div *ngIf="j!=23">
       {{y}}
     </div>
   </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: show your html and component class code.

Comment: Please edit it into your original question so that it is readable

Comment: use [(ngModel)] and a getter like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55914612/how-to-unchecked-all-checked-checkbox-in-angular-6/55915747#55915747

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of checkbox you need to pass a value in `(change)="dppflaggeedChecked('')"` function and retrive it in `dppflageedchecked()` in class.

```
 <tr id="trval" *ngFor="let x of csvData; index as i">
   <td id="td" (click)="click($event)" contenteditable *ngFor="let y of x;let j=index" [class.active]="i == selectedRow">
     <i *ngIf="j==0" id="removeicon" class="fa fa-times-circle icon " aria-hidden="true" readonly="true" (click)="deleterow($event)"></i>
     <div *ngIf="j==23" contenteditable>

       <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="chkbx[i]" id="dppcheck" (change)="dppflagchecked()"> <-- here

     </div>
     <div *ngIf="j!=23"> {{y}} </div>
   </td>
 </tr>
```

** i is an index of the checkbox, and `chkbx` is variable moreover an object which has a value of checkbox based on the index.

so in component, you will get like

```
chkbx = {
     0: true, or 1
     1: false or 0
};
```

otherwise, you can change the key name like `[(ngModel)]="chkbx['checkbox_'+i]"`
and in component, you will get

```
chkbx = {
     checkbox_0: true, or 1
     checkbox_1: false or 0
};
```